# how to access controller's getter methods in JSP pages - spring mvc

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

In Struts , we can access the 'getter' methods and member variables of an Action class in the corresponding view JSP , using `<S:..>` tags . How this works ?

Is there any way to do this in spring mvc ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that with spring-mvc. But you can:

- add the required data as request attribute in the method you are invoking
- annotate the method with `@ModelAttribute("foo")` and access the result with `${foo}` in the jsp

Answer (score 0):

In MVC, the view displays model data -- not controller data. Whatever member variables or getters you have in the controller (that the view needs for rendering) are most likely misplaced: it's a controller that acts like a model.

The view is only provided with the model map (wrapped in a ModelAndView instance).

Moreover, supposing you could call Controller.getSomething() with some tag library in the view, that would make the view bound to one controller (or at least to controllers providing that particular getter), which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I agree. So in struts the model data can be misplaced in controller ?